# How do I get the only one attribution in html when it has two or more same tags in that html?

Tags: python, java, html

I can't solve this problem. What I want to do is extract only one thing that matches `'href' in`

`the <a>tag`

But, I can't figure it out with my code.

here is HTML structure and code.

```
[
<li class="first impact"><div class="B_MyAd_"></div> 
*<a class="goodsBox-info" href="http://barogo.alba.co.kr/">**
 <span class="logo"> <img alt="Baro Inc"src="//imagelogo.alba.kr/data_image2/logo/brand/
20200916174910805.gif"/> </span> <span class="company">Baro.Inc</span> <span class="title"><span>New Rider Recruition</span></span> <span class="wrap"> <span class="local">National</span> <span class="pay"><span class="payLetter">confirm</span> <span class="payIcon talk"></span></span> </span> </a>
*<a class="brandHover" href="http://barogo.alba.co.kr/"  </a>*</li>, . ,,,,,,.
 ]
```

=================================================================================

```
browser.get("http://www.alba.co.kr/")

alba = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
brands = list(alba.find_all('li', {"class" : "impact"}, 'a.goodsBox-info'))
#print(brands)

for b in brands :
   if b('a', {"class" : "brandHover"}) : 
     b = b('a')["href"]
   
   print(b)
```

Comment: And what output do you get?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as "java"?

Comment: My output is    File "c:/Users/HP/Desktop/NomardCoder/Paint/scrpper.py", line 28, in <module>
    b = b('a')["href"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: oh it's my fault insert 'java' on it